# Dynamics 365 Online Claims-based or Active Directory (through federation) authentication

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-active-directory, microsoft-dynamics, claims-based-identity, dynamics-crm-online

I have implemented Azure Active Directory Oath2.0 authentication and now I have to implement Claims-Based and Active Directory authentication in Java for Dynamics 365 Online/On-Premise.

I'm following this topic: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334502.aspx and here it says that Dynamics 365 online supports the following authentication scenarios: Claims Based Authentication or Active Directory Through Federation.

The problem is that I don't know from where to start and what configurations have to be done. I've played with azure portal and with the dynamics 365 online admin panel, but just can't figure out what I have to do :).

Can I use some info from https:// login.microsoftonline.com//FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml to perform such authentications?
Do I need do install a local Active Directory server?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend looking through some Azure AD samples on how to setup oAuth2.0 to various Microsoft services.  The [dev landing page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-developers-guide) has tons of a great samples. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapp-java) is the java sample.

If you're trying to sign in purely Azure AD users the access some resources, then this is pretty straight forward.  You'll want to register an app in the Azure Portal, setup all the delegated permissions and app configs necessary (the sample will help with this), then use the ADAL library to perform the oAuth2.0 flow.  This flow will return back tokens that can be played to whatever service you requested access in the form of http requests.

Comment: Hello Daniel, I already did that. I'm now interested in Claims-Based and Active Directory Authentication.

Comment: The samples and steps I provided are to do claims based identity w/ Azure AD. When you do authentication/authorization w/ Azure AD (or any other IDP using oAuth or OIDC) you get back a token with claims about the user.  Hence, claims based identity/auth.

Comment: Ok, I'll have to ask some help. I just don't understand what authentication options I have, how should they be done and what configuration have to be done. Also someone is trying to authenticate to CRM 8.2 by using username, password and some organization service url "url/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc". Is this still supported? I haven't played with the SOAP Endpoint, only with the Web API?